# What is the logic of not regarding perturbative renormalizability as a fundamental requirement?

Tags: string-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory

I read a statement in Becker and Becker's *String Theory and M-Theory* page 2. After pointing out the non-renormalizablity of GR by the dimension of gravitational constant, it is said:

> Some physicists believe that perturbative renormalizability is not a fundamental requirement and try to quantize pure general relativity despite its nonrenormalizability. Loop quantum gravity is an example of this approach. Whatever one thinks of the logic, it is fair to say that despite a considerable amount of effort such attempts have not yet been very fruitful.

I am curious, what is the logic behind "perturbative renormalizability is not a fundamental requirement"?

Comment: Presumably that the non-renormalisability is an artefact of the perturbation technique being used, and that a non-perturbative treatment will produce finite results.

Comment: They're probably referring to the fact that one can view a given theory (such as Einstein gravity) as a low-energy effective theory in which case renormalizability isn't so relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_field_theory

Comment: Then the theory goes to high energy scale, the possible other irrelevant contributions will increase. The leading term starts lose the prediction power....

Comment: A specific case of John's comment - they may be referring to asymptotic safety, also know as non-perturbative renormalizability: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_safety_in_quantum_gravity

Comment: Another scenario making use of a non-trivial non-gaussian fixed point to build a perturbation theory is asymptotic freedom, as for example explained [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/18271/perturbative-renormalizability-fundamental-requirement?show=18277#a18277). However, asymtotic freedom does not correctly reproduce the black hole entropy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that Becker & Becker are referring to asymptotic safety, a theoretical programme that attempts to describe gravity with a quantum field theory.

The philosophy is that a QFT is defined and sensible at all energy scales so long as all of its couplings are always finite. The simplest way for that to be the case is if all couplings flow to UV fixed points. This is called asymptotic safety.

The couplings, however, needn't be small. The theory may well be non-perturbative (and not perturbatively renormalizable). The philosophy here is that nature is simply non-perturbative, whether you and I like it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems ("theories") may have finite and physical solutions whereas their perturbative treatments may have divergent terms. In this case the quality of the initial approximation determines the quality of the perturbation series, figuratively speaking. See **[this problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3504)** as an example.

Some other problems ("theories") may be initially wrong - they have wrong exact solutions and they then need modifications (often understood as "renormalization" of equation coefficients). For example, QED without counter-terms is wrong, its solutions are good for nothing. QED with counter-terms is another theory, it has more or less good exact solutions although its perturbative version still suffers from IR divergences. In case of QED, subtractions of counter-terms can only be made perturbatively. I have a **[toy model](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3702)** where it can be done exactly to show how and why it works.

GR, in my opinion, is a wrong theory - its exact solutions are non physical. Nobody knows how to modify it to get a reasonable theory good for quantization.

Comment: *"GR, in my opinion, is a wrong theory - its exact solutions are non physical."* Could you elaborate? Which solutions do you mean?

Comment: @JánLalinský: GR is a macroscopic theory for weak fields. It does not work for point-like bodies, it has non physical singularities. It is even worse than Classical Electrodynamics in this respect.

Comment: Thanks, that was my impression too. It seems any theory which works only with total field cannot handle point particles because the field is singular at the place where the particle is. Using many individual fields of point particles without self-forces works much better, at least in electromagnetic theory. May be something similar can be done for gravitation. But since the scale where gravity seems important is so much greater than the scale of the atoms, perhaps it is a bad idea to look for theory of gravity at the scale of these particles.

Comment: @JánLalinský: I gave a brief critics of CED here, for example: http://vladimirkalitvianski.wordpress.com/2013/11/12/on-the-higgs-fake-book-by-alexander-unzicker/